# Data is not inserting into relation table in H2 database for ManytoMany relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

In the H2 database `@ManytoMany` relationship mapping the data is not inserting into the relation table i.e. BOOK_TAG.

I have 2 table Books and tag as below. It's working for MySQL, but not for H2 DB

Book.java

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "BOOK_TAG", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID") }
)
Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet();
```

Tag.java

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
Set<Book> books;
```

I'm using `BookRepository` and `BookRepository.saveAndFlush(books)` for saving the object.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, String> {
 //Repo methods
}
```

I can see the insert statement is getting generated as below but not inserting the data into `BOOK_TAG` table. Any help would be appreciated.

> [EL Fine]: sql: 2023-05-25
> 10:57:16.262--ClientSession(1130156479)--Connection(1364346258)--INSERT
> INTO BOOK_TAG (TAG_ID, BOOK_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
> bind => [1, 897bead1-ed8e-4c6b-897b-bkid]

Comment: okey, but how it's working for mysql database ?

Comment: I've removed readOnly=true and used only "@Transactional" for repository class, but still same issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50227160/7012221 check once